# Android studio 0.211 doesn't support signing apk any more

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, signing

I don't know when android studio abandon the UI for signing the apk which is such a convenient method. They just popup a window with the following message:

[image]

Are there any guide to do this (I'm totally no clue about Gradle-based projects)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

0.2.13 reintroduced this feature.

Anyway you can add this to your build.gradle script:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            storePassword "******"
            keyAlias "******"
            keyPassword "******"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

You can see this link

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations